# How to set UIBarButtonItem with out border

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I have created view with barbutton as follows

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingsicon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(settingsButtonClicked:)];
```

[image]

It is comming like this
but I want it as

[image]

how can I remove the border of the button?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this :

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

You can initialize a button with whatever view you would like. You can make a button with any (acceptable) view inside it.

eg.

```
// GRAPHICAL BUTTON FRAMEWORK
     UIButton* btton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [btton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
     [btton addTarget:self action:@selector(SOMEROUTINE) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [btton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SOME IMAGE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     UIBarButtonItem* barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btton];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 14):

Another way is to remove button's background image:

```
// portrait
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
// landscape
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for me this is the best solution if you just want to remove the button background, for example if you want to keep the same button style in iOS6 and iOS7.

Comment: perfect! the most simplest solution